# I want to divide my row into 1/4 ratio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to divide my row *in flutter* into 4 columns with the same width. So far, the solution I came up with is this,

```
   child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Is there any alternative to this. Also dividing the row into 1/3 ratio would not work in this method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an `Expanded Widget`

Check the code below:

It works perfectly well.

> 1) For 1/3 ratio

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

> 1) For 1/4 ratio

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.yellow),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

See output below:

[image]

[image]

I hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Expanded` or `Flexible`, by default it has `flex: 1`, and you can change the values depending on your need.

```
  Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1, // you can play with this value, by default it is 1
        child: Child1(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1, 
        child: Child2(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1, 
        child: Child3(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1, 
        child: Child4(),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

As it's not mentioned in the above solutions. Flex is the proportion to be occupied in the available widget. If you're using 2 Expanded widgets one with flex 1 and the other with flex 3 then available space will be occupied as 1/4 by the first Expanded widget and 3/4 by the other.